# Shape error when adding Embedding Layer in Keras Model for NLP classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I have a text classification problem with 4 different classes. I have converted the classes into one-hot representation. This is how I have processed the X data:
[image]

[image]

Using these parameters I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 500, 4) are incompatible
```

Comment: your target is 2D... you need a flatten, global pooling or an LSTM/GRU with return_sequences=False

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify input_shape parameter with equal to max_length or x_train_padded.shape[1] in Embedding Layer so that it can pass through Dense Layer in a featured representation manner